# Did Kim Clement Predict 9/11?

Tags: 9-11, christianity, divination, osama-bin-laden

Recently many Christian commentators have told me that a Christian prophet by the name of Kim Clement predicted 9/11 (0:18), the location of Osama bin Laden (0:37), the rival of Ford (1:00), The emergence of ISIS (1:17), Hurricane Katrina (1:35), and a Christian rival in Egypt (1:52).

Video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgM5bA7KiTY&authuser=0

I again want to know if the video is accurate in its dating of the prophecies and if these events could be predicated without "supernatural intervention"?

Thank You

Comment: Surely the same answer made to your previous Kim Clement question applies to this one and any other such claims. Hard to assume good faith here.

Comment: @JeromeViveiros These claims are more specific.

Comment: "the revival of Ford" As in the car company? Or something else?

Comment: Last time you asked a very similar question, I edited the transcription into the question, inlined the link, and removed the "Thank you" to show you how it is done here. Please do the same for this one.

Comment: The title of this question asks about 1 prediction, but the text asks about 6 unrelated predictions. We already have [a question about a 7th claim](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/54156/26673), and the answers will always be basically the same: cherry-picking and entirely plausible coincidence.

Comment: I predicted 9/11. Not explicitly but for years prior I'd been expecting something like what happened to occur. Maybe not the exact events that happened, but a major muslim attack on the USA or UK. Of course AQ had tried to bring down the WTC towers before, using a truck bomb in the parking garage, and failed. So it wasn't too much a stretch of the imagination that they'd try again.

Answer (score 15):

## Cherry Picking

In order to actually determine whether Kim Clement is actually making predictions we would need to analyze the complete corpus of his statements. He says a lot. Highlight reels such as this video are likely cherry picking the ones which are closest to reality.

For example, if he made 100 predictions of terrorist attacks and they picked 2 that had a passing resemblance to reality for this video, what about the other 98?

## The Claims

With that out of the way, let's go through how well the chosen statements match up with their claims. I prophesize it won't go well.

### July 25th, 1996. 9/11: *Wrong.*

> There has been a terrorist act. America will retaliate. For what they did to our people, as they flew in the air over Long Island.

The World Trade Center was located on Manhattan Island. Long Island is adjacent to Manhattan. However, neither [AA 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_11) nor [UA 175](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_175) flew over Long Island.

[image]
[image]

### Nov 1st, 2004. Osama Bin Laden's death: *Wrong.*

> Today, I was given a vision, about the whereabouts, of Osama Bin Laden. It was in a city close  to Faisalabad, Pakistan.

The video juxtaposes this with an announcement that Osama Bin Laden is dead. Kim never says Osama Bin Laden is dead, he just says where he will be. Maybe he was in Faisalabad at some point, it's not hard to guess that he'd be somewhere in Pakistan.

As for the video's implied claim, [Osama Bin Laden died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_Osama_bin_Laden) in Abbottabad, Pakistan about (eyeballing it) 150-200 miles away from Faisalabad.

[image]

### April 8th, 2006. Revival of Ford? *Binary.*

> God says, Ford will be revived!

Presumably he's referring to Ford Motors' financial woes at the time. I don't know why God would care about a car company, or what constitutes it being "revived". It would seem to be a binary prediction: either Ford would recover from its financial woes at the tine, or it wouldn't. Given they've been around since 1903, I'd bank on them sticking around.

But this is also another vague one. What if Ford went bankrupt and got bought by another car company which retained the brand? Does that count as "revived"?

### July 8th, 2006. An Earthquake in Japan. *Obvious.*

> This one nation, shall experience, what they predicted for this nation, an earthquake in Japan.

[Japan experienced major earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earthquakes_in_Japan) in 1998, 2001, 2003, 2004, and two in 2005. You don't need God to tell you there will be more.

### March 20th, 2014. ISIS: *Generic.*

> A new group of terrorists are emerging,  they will train pilots to plunge, 
> to attack, to steal.

Not hard to predict there will be a new terrorist group somewhere, somewhen. However, "train pilots to plunge" is evocative of pilots crashing planes into monuments 9/11 style. AFAIK ISIS never did this.

### July 22, 2005. Hurricane Katrina: *Edited.*

> Oh, New Orleans, enough of this, enough! [edit] I will take up the men that have  stood in faith, raise them above the flood, that shall destroy those that constantly  bicker, and stand against my servant Moses.

These are two statements edited together to appear to be one audio clip. Without the original clip we cannot know what he actually said.

### February 18th, 2011. Egyptians singing "Yeshua": *Normal.*

> What is happening in Egypt, they'll get tired of singing Allah, they'll start singing about Yeshua.

"Yeshua" or "yasue" or "يسوع" is an Egyptian term for "Jesus". The implication is that Egyptians will suddenly convert to Christianity.

The connected clip of people in Cairo, Egypt chanting "Yeshua" is from "A Night of Prayer and Return to God", an event for Egyptian Christians. This is not unusual, [10% of Egyptians are Christian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Egypt).

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but what's the precedent if this user asks more "Did Kim Clement predict" questions? Refer them back to your mention of cherry picking or treat each one as a specific claim?

Comment: +1 Slight suggestion for improvement - nobody would describe Abbottabad as "close to Faisalabad" when the much larger city of Islamabad is closer.

Comment: @DJClayworth The claim doesn't involve Islamabad. What's the improvement?

Comment: @JeromeViveiros They're a new user. We'll vote to close that bridge if we come to it and explain why.

Comment: The Arabic name for Jesus is: عِيسَى, ʿĪsā.  The name יֵשׁוּעַ "Yeshua" is Hebrew, and is the equivalent of the English name "Joshua", which means saviour. — ([Daniel Kahn's Yiddish version of Leonard Cohen's "*Hallelujah*"](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Music/lyrics/Haleluye/) uses "Yeshua" to rhyme with "Haleluye".)

Comment: @Schwern: I understand DJClayworth's proposal to be something like this: one might argue that Abottabad is a small town, so the prophet might have used the name of a larger city in the vicinity. However, if that were the prophet's intention, they would have used the name of the much closer, much larger, and much more well-known city Islamabad, after all, the capital of Pakistan.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Using the smaller city makes the prediction more specific and impressive. "He's near Chicago" vs "He's near Dearborn". Doesn't really matter, he's off by over 100 miles anyway.